# NServiceBus Gateway IOC and MessageHandler issue

Tags: castle-windsor, nservicebus

I've setup a NSB Gateway demo project which all works fine. (SiteA sends msg to SiteB, and SiteB reply a confirmation. ie.Bus.Reply())

Then I went ahead using .CatleWindsorBuilder() instead of the .DefaultBuilder().
mostly working, got my custom types injected. however, exception thrown when Bus.Reply() at SiteB.

```
Bus.Reply<CustomerOrderReceived>(m => { m.BranchOffice = "US"; m.Description = message.Description; });
```

The exception is:  "No handlers could be found for message type: CustomerOrderReceived"
It sounds like it couldn't find the SiteA's `OrderReceivedMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<CustomerOrderReceived>`

Here's SiteA's EndpointConfig

```
_container = new WindsorContainer();

        Configure.With()
            .CastleWindsorBuilder(_container)
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport().IsTransactional(true)
            .FileShareDataBus(".\\databus").UnicastBus().ImpersonateSender(false).LoadMessageHandlers();

        _container.Register(Component.For<IOrderTask>().ImplementedBy<OrderTask>());
        _container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(_container));
        _container.Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication());
```

however the message handlers within SiteA all works fine.

Wondering if someone have the working sample of Castle Windsor IOC in NSB? I just couldn't find anything useful on google.

Comment: With the CastleWindsorBuilder(), the handler works fine when             Bus.SendLocal(new CustomerOrderConfirmed()) from SiteA. The exception "handler can't not be found" only throw when Bus.Reply() from SiteB. I almost think this is a NSB bug??

Comment: Which version of NSB is this?  Does the Gateway sample that comes with NSB work if you change their config to be use .CastleWindsorBuilder()?

Comment: i downloaded last week, it's the latest 3.3.3 this proof of concept demo is pretty much based on the gateway sample comes with the nsb installer. all works beautifully when using the DefaultBuilder(). but when replacing with WindsorBuilder I got this annoying glitch. stuck on this for 2 days. Wondering if this is the NSB bug or not? Do you have any working sample using WindsorBuilder for Gateway scenario? or can you suggest a better IOC to use? ie. StructureMapBuilder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got is sorted! by using  StructureMapBuilder()

However, now I believe it's the NSB bug when handling Bus.Reply() in Gateway scenario.

Comment: Thanks Luc we're looking into it. I'll report back the results here